# Oracle EBS collection plan element triggers and SQL validation parameters

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

In Oracle EBS, you can create triggers for collection plan elements. Those triggers can use SQL validation, i.e. you can supply a SQL statement for field validation. From the documentation that I've found, it shows that you can insert :parameter.org_id and :parameter.user_id into the SQL and the correct value will be substituted.
In our web app, we're reading that SQL validation string ourselves and executing it. We'd like to use more than just those two parameters. though.

The question is: 
can we use parameters other than org_id and user_id?

Comment: I have no idea, but - why don't you just try it?

Comment: When I think of EBS and collection plans, I immediately go to the ASCP application.  Please confirm.

Comment: If we are talking about the EBS collection plan for ASCP (which is a concurrent program), you could make a copy of it and add additional parameters (the ones you need). Have you tried that?

Comment: No, not using ASCP for this. Our web app is an extension of EBS and so does a lot of WIP and QA activities. Part of what we do is display a collection plan during the processing of one of a job's operations.

Comment: I haven't just tried it because I'm not actually an EBS expert and rarely use the EBS application itself. Our app directly accesses the EBD database,